# Dynamic struct inside of struct

Tags: c, struct

I can't quite figure out how to do this, I've tried this and several variations and some will compile and seemingly work ok but I'll get very random segfaults and it has something to do with the way I'm declaring these structs. All the info in the structs are dynamic. Please let me know the proper way to do this, thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct 
{
    char* s2string1;
    char* s2string2;
    int   s2int1;
} struct2;


typedef struct 
{
    char*    s1string1;
    char*    s1string2;
    struct struct2* mystruct;
    int      int1;    
} struct1;


struct struct2* RetS2(char* CopyMe)
{
    int* Array = (int*) malloc (sizeof (int) * 5);
    Array[0] = strlen (CopyMe);

    struct struct2* S2 = (struct struct2*) malloc ( sizeof (struct2) );

    S2->s2int1 = Array[0];

    return S2;

}


struct struct1* RetS1()
{
     struct struct1* S1 = (struct struct1*) malloc ( sizeof (struct1) );

     struct struct2* S2 = RetS2();

     S1->mystruct = S2;

     S1->int1 = S2->S2int1; 


     return S1;
}

int main()
{

    struct struct1 Top = RetS1();

    if (Top->mystruct->s2int1 == 10)
        // do something

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot have a "dynamic" struct in a struct. What you can have (and what you use) is a pointer to a struct in another struct. But that is not different from any other pointer to a struct.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! And enable warnings and pay heed to them!

Comment: Do you always just drop everything you no longer need on the ground?

Comment: @EOF: Some people have their mom clean up after them. Perhaps they better use a garbage collected language:-)

Comment: @Olaf: I wish garbage-collection also collected garbage programs.

Comment: `struct struct2` doesn't seem legal. You can use just `struct2` instead

Answer (score 1):

Your code has multiple issues:

1. **This is the main issue**:

   `RetS2`'s function definition is

   ```
   struct struct2* RetS2(char* CopyMe)
   ```

   which means that it expects a `char*` as its first argument. But when you call it:

   ```
   struct struct2* S2 = RetS2();
   ```

   you don't pass an arguments. This invokes *Undefined Behavior*.
2. Here:

   ```
   int* Array = (int*) malloc (sizeof (int) * 5);
   ```

   You allocate memory for 5 `int`s. You use the first element of the array and stops using it. You also forgot the `free` the allocated memory for `Array`.
3. The cast in `malloc` (and family) [is not required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) in C.
4. You don't `free` the `malloc`ed memory for `S2` and `S1`.

Comment: Thanks cool guy, but I fixed everything and still get the crash. Can someone give me a simple yes/no answer if I'm declaring the memory for structs properly? That is all I'm asking.

Comment: You still get the crash? What did you change `struct struct2* S2 = RetS2();` to? And the memory allocation is correct. But see issue #2 in my answer. Also, you should check the result of `malloc` to see if it was successful and should also `free` the allocated memory(See issue #4)

Comment: Yes I know about free but free'ing the memory is not the issue here. Anyways thanks it must be something else.

Comment: Yes. It is. Again, What did you change `struct struct2* S2 = RetS2();` to?